# vb.net 2015 winodowsapplication1 (debugging) mode form not refreshing

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net 2015 but I am using vb6 for more than few years.

I am crating new form with three buttons and placed Toggle brakepoint at button1_click1(..) 1st line of code.  On clicking button in **debug mode**, execution stopping at 1st line and on **pressing F11 key cursor moving with yellow highlight to next line** and so on....  But I am watching form nothing is getting changed in executed form unless I execute command refresh after every line (just to watch form changes) or completion of whole sub that is on moving out of end sub form getting refreshed.

But in vb6 on moving out of every line form was getting changed.

Can anyone please help me out how to get form automatically get refreshed on moving out from every line of code.  Thanks

[1) Before Refresh() code  2) After Refresh() Code  3) VB6 not like vb.net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0LvX.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

While I know that does not resolve your problem... It is working as designed. Please look at the following link, it may give you some ideas
[Blank Form When Debugging](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/466862-blank-form-when-debugging)